# sql in but with multiple column

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have final sql query like this

```
UPDATE Booking 
set BookingType='Booked'
where BookingType='Defaulter' and BookingId in(SELECT BookingID
FROM ScheduledDues WHERE projectID=@ProjectId and DueFrom <= GETDATE()
GROUP BY BookingID HAVING MAX(DueTill) =0)
```

Now what i want is that select column to contains ScheduleDues with order by ScheduleDues desc. but cannot do it because it contains in. how can i do it?

```
  SELECT BookingID,Max(DueTill),ScheduledDueID
    FROM ScheduledDues WHERE projectID=30 and DueFrom <= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY BookingID ,ScheduledDueID order by ScheduledDueID desc
```

Comment: Really don't understand what you're trying to achieve here. The second query doesn't have an `IN` clause (even with incorrect syntax), so it's unclear. Can you elaborate further? Perhaps add some sample data and expected results.

Comment: I WANT SECOND QUERY IN MY FIRST QUERY AFTER IN

Comment: No need to SHOUT. 

Comment: no i am not shouting :)

Comment: We all heard you! :)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question correctly, is this what you try to achieve?

```
SELECT 
      ScheduledDues.BookingID
    , ScheduledDues.DueTill
    -- or you could type , InnerTable.MaxDueTill
    , ScheduledDues.ScheduledDueID
FROM (
    SELECT BookingID, Max(DueTill) AS MaxDueTill
    FROM ScheduledDues 
    WHERE projectID=30 and DueFrom <= GETDATE()
    GROUP BY BookingID ) InnerTable
JOIN ScheduledDues 
     ON InnerTable.BookingID = ScheduledDues.BookingID
     AND InnerTable.MaxDueTill = ScheduledDues.DueTill
ORDER BY ScheduledDueID DESC
```

Thus for each booking (that can have multiple Schedule-Ids) you want the schedule-id associated with the maximum due-date. Meaning that for each booking, you get one schedule-id. And you wish to order that schedule-id. (And with the schedule-id being in the original group-by, you got all schedule-ids and not just the one you were looking for.)